# An ANTLR grammar for Scheme's quasiquotations

Tags: scheme, antlr, context-free-grammar, r5rs

Considering following grammar in EBNF: 
http://pauillac.inria.fr/cdrom_a_graver/www/bigloo/manual/r5rs-8.html

The quasiquotations grammar given there is not context free:

```
<quasiquotation> --> <quasiquotation 1>
<qq template 0> --> <expression>
<quasiquotation D> --> `<qq template D>
       | (quasiquote <qq template D>)
<qq template D> --> <simple datum>
       | <list qq template D>
       | <vector qq template D>
       | <unquotation D>
<list qq template D> --> (<qq template or splice D>*)
       | (<qq template or splice D>+ .  <qq template D>)
       | '<qq template D>
       | <quasiquotation D+1>
<vector qq template D> --> #(<qq template or splice D>*)
<unquotation D> --> ,<qq template D-1>
       | (unquote <qq template D-1>)
<qq template or splice D> --> <qq template D>
       | <splicing unquotation D>
<splicing unquotation D> --> ,@<qq template D-1>
       | (unquote-splicing <qq template D-1>)
```

Is it possible to define a grammar for this in ANTLR, although it is designed for context-free grammars?

Comment: D is a natural number and defines the 'levels' of abstraction. its like an "inductive" build rule. see http://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/gauche-refe_30.html for a good explanation and also some samples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameters to both lexer- and parser rules by adding `[int d]` after it, like this: `foo[int d] : ... ;`. Passing the parameter `1` to rule `foo` is as simple as `parse : foo[1];`:

Of course, it need not be an `int`, but can be any type.

So, in your case, do something like this:

```js
quasiquotation
  :  quasiquotationD[1]
  ;

quasiquotationD[int d]
  :  '`' qqTemplate[d]
  |  '(' QUASIQUOTE qqTemplate[d] ')'
  ;

qqTemplate[int d]
  :  (expression)=>  expression
  |  ('(' UNQUOTE)=> unquotation[d]
  |                  simpleDatum
  |                  vectorQQTemplate[d]
  |                  listQQTemplate[d]
  ;

vectorQQTemplate[int d]
  :  '#(' qqTemplateOrSplice[d]* ')'
  ;

listQQTemplate[int d]
  :                     '\'' qqTemplate[d]
  |  ('(' QUASIQUOTE)=> quasiquotationD[d+1]
  |                     '(' (qqTemplateOrSplice[d]+ ('.' qqTemplate[d])?)? ')'
  ;

unquotation[int d]
  :  ',' qqTemplate[d-1]
  |  '(' UNQUOTE qqTemplate[d-1] ')'
  ;

qqTemplateOrSplice[int d]
  :  ('(' UNQUOTE_SPLICING)=> splicingUnquotation[d]
  |                           qqTemplate[d]
  ;

splicingUnquotation[int d]
  :  ',@' qqTemplate[d-1]
  |  '(' UNQUOTE_SPLICING qqTemplate[d-1] ')'
  ;
```

Note that there are also some syntactic predicates, `( ... )=>`, to account for some ambiguities in the grammar.

For a complete version of the R5RS spec in ANTLR, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344766/antlr-resolving-non-ll-problems-and-syntactic-predicates/6349009#6349009).