# ANTLR resolving non-LL(*) problems and syntactic predicates

Tags: scheme, antlr, r5rs, predicates

consider following rules in the parser:

```
expression 
    :   IDENTIFIER
    |   (...)
    |   procedure_call // e.g. (foo 1 2 3)
    |   macro_use   // e.g. (xyz (some datum))
    ;

procedure_call
    :   '(' expression expression* ')'
    ;

macro_use
    :   '(' IDENTIFIER datum* ')'
    ;
```

and

```
// Note that any string that parses as an <expression> will also parse as a <datum>.
datum 
    : simple_datum 
    | compound_datum
    ;

simple_datum 
    :   BOOLEAN
    |   NUMBER
    |   CHARACTER
    |   STRING
    |   IDENTIFIER
    ;

compound_datum 
    : list 
    | vector
    ;

list 
    :   '(' (datum+ ( '.' datum)?)? ')'
    |   ABBREV_PREFIX datum
    ;

fragment ABBREV_PREFIX
    :   ('\''   | '`' | ',' | ',@')
    ;

vector 
    : '#(' datum* ')'
    ;
```

the procedure_call and macro_rule alternative in the expression rule generate an non-LL(*) structure error. I can see the problem, since `(IDENTIFIER)` will parse as both. but even when i define both with + instead of *, it generates the error, even though above example shouldn't be parsing anymore. 
i came up with the usage of syntactic predicates, but i can't figure out how to use them to do the trick here. 
something like

```
expression 
    :   IDENTIFIER 
    |   (...)
    |   (procedure_call)=>procedure_call // e.g. (foo 1 2 3)
    |   macro_use   // e.g. (xyz (some datum))
    ;
```

or

```
expression 
    :   IDENTIFIER
    |   (...)
    |   ('(' IDENTIFIER expression)=>procedure_call // e.g. (foo 1 2 3)
    |   macro_use   // e.g. (xyz (some datum))
    ;
```

doesnt work either, since none but the first rule will match anything. is there a proper way to solve that?

Comment: If I have time, I'll have a closer look at this. As for now, one thing springs out: you're using `fragment` rules inside parser rules which is illegal. Only lexer rules can use `fragment` rules. Specifically: `ABBREV_PREFIX` cannot be used inside `list`.

Comment: expression and datam can both match IDENTIFIER so procedure_call and macro_use can both match `( IDENTIFIER IDENTIFIER )` if you change * to + in those rules. The first syntactic predicate modification should resolve this. What is broken about it?

Comment: Using syntactic predicates, `( ... )=>`, _is_ the way to go here. You probably didn't use enough of them (can't tell for sure without seeing more of the grammar). Anyway, have a look at my answer.

Comment: For `'(' expression expression* ')'` you can always put `'(' expression+ ')'` as they have exactly the same meaning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [JavaCC grammar of R5RS](http://mindprod.com/javacc/R5RS.jj) which I used to (quickly!) write an ANTLR equivalent:

```java
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 by Bart Kiers, based on the work done by Håkan L. Younes'
 * JavaCC R5RS grammar, available at: http://mindprod.com/javacc/R5RS.jj
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */
grammar R5RS;

parse
  :  commandOrDefinition* EOF
  ;

commandOrDefinition
  :  (syntaxDefinition)=>              syntaxDefinition
  |  (definition)=>                    definition
  |  ('(' BEGIN commandOrDefinition)=> '(' BEGIN commandOrDefinition+ ')'
  |                                    command
  ;

syntaxDefinition
  :  '(' DEFINE_SYNTAX keyword transformerSpec ')'
  ;

definition
  :  '(' DEFINE ( variable expression ')'
                | '(' variable defFormals ')' body ')'
                )
  |  '(' BEGIN definition* ')'
  ;

defFormals
  :  variable* ('.' variable)?
  ;

keyword
  :  identifier
  ;

transformerSpec
  :  '(' SYNTAX_RULES '(' identifier* ')' syntaxRule* ')'
  ;

syntaxRule
  :  '(' pattern template ')'
  ;

pattern
  :  patternIdentifier
  |  '(' (pattern+ ('.' pattern | ELLIPSIS)?)?  ')'
  |  '#(' (pattern+ ELLIPSIS? )? ')'
  |  patternDatum
  ;

patternIdentifier
  :  syntacticKeyword
  |  VARIABLE
  ;

patternDatum
  :  STRING
  |  CHARACTER
  |  bool
  |  number
  ;

template
  :  patternIdentifier
  |  '(' (templateElement+ ('.' templateElement)?)? ')'
  |  '#(' templateElement* ')'
  |  templateDatum
  ;

templateElement
  :  template ELLIPSIS?
  ;

templateDatum
  :  patternDatum
  ;

command
  :  expression
  ;

identifier
  :  syntacticKeyword
  |  variable
  ;

syntacticKeyword
  :  expressionKeyword
  |  ELSE
  |  ARROW
  |  DEFINE
  |  UNQUOTE
  |  UNQUOTE_SPLICING
  ;  

expressionKeyword
  :  QUOTE
  |  LAMBDA
  |  IF
  |  SET
  |  BEGIN
  |  COND
  |  AND
  |  OR
  |  CASE
  |  LET
  |  LETSTAR
  |  LETREC
  |  DO
  |  DELAY
  |  QUASIQUOTE
  ;  

expression
  :  (variable)=>          variable
  |  (literal)=>           literal
  |  (lambdaExpression)=>  lambdaExpression
  |  (conditional)=>       conditional
  |  (assignment)=>        assignment
  |  (derivedExpression)=> derivedExpression
  |  (procedureCall)=>     procedureCall
  |  (macroUse)=>          macroUse
  |                        macroBlock
  ;

variable
  :  VARIABLE
  |  ELLIPSIS
  ;

literal
  :  quotation
  |  selfEvaluating
  ;

quotation
  :  '\'' datum
  |  '(' QUOTE datum ')'
  ;

selfEvaluating
  :  bool
  |  number
  |  CHARACTER
  |  STRING
  ;

lambdaExpression
  :  '(' LAMBDA formals body ')'
  ;

formals
  :  '(' (variable+ ('.' variable)?)? ')'
  |  variable
  ;

conditional
  :  '(' IF test consequent alternate? ')'
  ;

test 
  :  expression
  ;

consequent  
  :  expression
  ;

alternate 
  :  expression
  ;

assignment
  :  '(' SET variable expression ')'
  ;

derivedExpression
  :  quasiquotation
  |  '(' ( COND ( '(' ELSE sequence ')'
                | condClause+ ('(' ELSE sequence ')')? 
                )
         | CASE expression ( '(' ELSE sequence ')'
                           | caseClause+ ('(' ELSE sequence ')')? 
                           )
         | AND test*
         | OR test*
         | LET variable? '(' bindingSpec* ')' body
         | LETSTAR '(' bindingSpec* ')' body
         | LETREC '(' bindingSpec* ')' body
         | BEGIN sequence
         | DO '(' iterationSpec* ')' '(' test doResult? ')' command*
         | DELAY expression
         ) 
     ')'
  ;

condClause
  :  '(' test (sequence | ARROW recipient)? ')'
  ;

recipient
  :  expression
  ;

caseClause
  :  '(' '(' datum* ')' sequence ')'
  ;

bindingSpec
  :  '(' variable expression ')'
  ;

iterationSpec
  :  '(' variable init step? ')'
  ;

init
  :  expression
  ;

step
  :  expression
  ;

doResult
  :  sequence
  ;

procedureCall
  :  '(' operator operand* ')'
  ;

operator
  :  expression
  ;

operand
  :  expression
  ;

macroUse
  :  '(' keyword datum* ')'
  ;

macroBlock
  :  '(' (LET_SYNTAX | LETREC_SYNTAX) '(' syntaxSpec* ')' body ')'
  ;

syntaxSpec
  :  '(' keyword transformerSpec ')'
  ;

body
  :  ((definition)=> definition)* sequence
  ;

//sequence
//  :  ((command)=> command)* expression
//  ;

sequence
  :  expression+
  ;

datum
  :  simpleDatum
  |  compoundDatum
  ;

simpleDatum
  :  bool
  |  number
  |  CHARACTER
  |  STRING
  |  identifier
  ;

compoundDatum
  :  list
  |  vector
  ;

list
  :  '(' (datum+ ('.' datum)?)? ')'
  |  abbreviation
  ;

abbreviation
  :  abbrevPrefix datum
  ;

abbrevPrefix
  :  '\'' | '`' | ',@' | ','
  ;

vector
  :  '#(' datum* ')'
  ;

number
  :  NUM_2
  |  NUM_8
  |  NUM_10
  |  NUM_16
  ;

bool
  :  TRUE
  |  FALSE
  ;

quasiquotation
  :  quasiquotationD[1]
  ;

quasiquotationD[int d]
  :  '`' qqTemplate[d]
  |  '(' QUASIQUOTE qqTemplate[d] ')'
  ;

qqTemplate[int d]
  :  (expression)=>  expression
  |  ('(' UNQUOTE)=> unquotation[d]
  |                  simpleDatum
  |                  vectorQQTemplate[d]
  |                  listQQTemplate[d]
  ;

vectorQQTemplate[int d]
  :  '#(' qqTemplateOrSplice[d]* ')'
  ;

listQQTemplate[int d]
  :                     '\'' qqTemplate[d]
  |  ('(' QUASIQUOTE)=> quasiquotationD[d+1]
  |                     '(' (qqTemplateOrSplice[d]+ ('.' qqTemplate[d])?)? ')'
  ;

unquotation[int d]
  :  ',' qqTemplate[d-1]
  |  '(' UNQUOTE qqTemplate[d-1] ')'
  ;

qqTemplateOrSplice[int d]
  :  ('(' UNQUOTE_SPLICING)=> splicingUnquotation[d]
  |                           qqTemplate[d]
  ;

splicingUnquotation[int d]
  :  ',@' qqTemplate[d-1]
  |  '(' UNQUOTE_SPLICING qqTemplate[d-1] ')'
  ;

// macro keywords
LET_SYNTAX       : 'let-syntax';
LETREC_SYNTAX    : 'letrec-syntax';
SYNTAX_RULES     : 'syntax-rules';
DEFINE_SYNTAX    : 'define-syntax';

// syntactic keywords
ELSE             : 'else';
ARROW            : '=>';
DEFINE           : 'define';
UNQUOTE_SPLICING : 'unquote-splicing';
UNQUOTE          : 'unquote';

// expression keywords
QUOTE            : 'quote';
LAMBDA           : 'lambda';
IF               : 'if';
SET              : 'set!';
BEGIN            : 'begin';
COND             : 'cond';
AND              : 'and';
OR               : 'or';
CASE             : 'case';
LET              : 'let';
LETSTAR          : 'let*';
LETREC           : 'letrec';
DO               : 'do';
DELAY            : 'delay';
QUASIQUOTE       : 'quasiquote';

NUM_2  : PREFIX_2 COMPLEX_2;
NUM_8  : PREFIX_8 COMPLEX_8;
NUM_10 : PREFIX_10? COMPLEX_10;
NUM_16 : PREFIX_16 COMPLEX_16;

ELLIPSIS : '...';

VARIABLE 
  :  INITIAL SUBSEQUENT* 
  |  PECULIAR_IDENTIFIER
  ;

STRING : '"' STRING_ELEMENT* '"';

CHARACTER : '#\\' (~(' ' | '\n') | CHARACTER_NAME);

TRUE  : '#' ('t' | 'T');
FALSE : '#' ('f' | 'F');

// to ignore
SPACE   : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
COMMENT : ';' ~('\r' | '\n')* {$channel=HIDDEN;};

// fragments  
fragment INITIAL : LETTER | SPECIAL_INITIAL;
fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment SPECIAL_INITIAL : '!' | '$' | '%' | '&' | '*' | '/' | ':' | '<' | '=' | '>' | '?' | '^' | '_' | '~';
fragment SUBSEQUENT : INITIAL | DIGIT | SPECIAL_SUBSEQUENT;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment SPECIAL_SUBSEQUENT : '.' | '+' | '-' | '@';
fragment PECULIAR_IDENTIFIER : '+' | '-';
fragment STRING_ELEMENT : ~('"' | '\\') | '\\' ('"' | '\\');
fragment CHARACTER_NAME : 'space' | 'newline';

fragment COMPLEX_2 
  :  REAL_2 ('@' REAL_2)?
  |  REAL_2? SIGN UREAL_2? ('i' | 'I')
  ;

fragment COMPLEX_8 
  :  REAL_8 ('@' REAL_8)?
  |  REAL_8? SIGN UREAL_8? ('i' | 'I')
  ;

fragment COMPLEX_10 
  :  REAL_10 ('@' REAL_10)?
  |  REAL_10? SIGN UREAL_10? ('i' | 'I')
  ;

fragment COMPLEX_16 
  :  REAL_16 ('@' REAL_16)?
  |  REAL_16? SIGN UREAL_16? ('i' | 'I')
  ;

fragment REAL_2 : SIGN? UREAL_2;
fragment REAL_8 : SIGN? UREAL_8;
fragment REAL_10 : SIGN? UREAL_10;
fragment REAL_16 : SIGN? UREAL_16;
fragment UREAL_2 : UINTEGER_2 ('/' UINTEGER_2)?;
fragment UREAL_8 : UINTEGER_8 ('/' UINTEGER_8)?;
fragment UREAL_10 : UINTEGER_10 ('/' UINTEGER_10)? | DECIMAL_10;
fragment UREAL_16 : UINTEGER_16 ('/' UINTEGER_16)?;

fragment DECIMAL_10 
  :  UINTEGER_10 SUFFIX
  |  '.' DIGIT+ '#'* SUFFIX?
  |  DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT* '#'* SUFFIX?
  |  DIGIT+ '#'+ '.' '#'* SUFFIX?
  ;

fragment UINTEGER_2 : DIGIT_2+ '#'*;
fragment UINTEGER_8 : DIGIT_8+ '#'*;
fragment UINTEGER_10 : DIGIT+ '#'*;
fragment UINTEGER_16 : DIGIT_16+ '#'*;
fragment PREFIX_2 : RADIX_2 EXACTNESS? | EXACTNESS RADIX_2;
fragment PREFIX_8 : RADIX_8 EXACTNESS? | EXACTNESS RADIX_8;
fragment PREFIX_10 : RADIX_10 EXACTNESS? | EXACTNESS RADIX_10;
fragment PREFIX_16 : RADIX_16 EXACTNESS? | EXACTNESS RADIX_16;
fragment SUFFIX : EXPONENT_MARKER SIGN? DIGIT+;
fragment EXPONENT_MARKER : 'e' | 's' | 'f' | 'd' | 'l' | 'E' | 'S' | 'F' | 'D' | 'L';
fragment SIGN : '+' | '-';
fragment EXACTNESS : '#' ('i' | 'e' | 'I' | 'E');
fragment RADIX_2 : '#' ('b' | 'B');
fragment RADIX_8 : '#' ('o' | 'O');
fragment RADIX_10 : '#' ('d' | 'D');
fragment RADIX_16 : '#' ('x' | 'X');
fragment DIGIT_2 : '0' | '1';
fragment DIGIT_8 : '0'..'7';
fragment DIGIT_16 : DIGIT | 'a'..'f' | 'A'..'F';
```

which can be tested with the following class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = 
        "(define sum-iter                        \n" + 
        "  (lambda(n acc i)                      \n" + 
        "    (if (> i n)                         \n" + 
        "      acc                               \n" + 
        "      (sum-iter n (+ acc i) (+ i 1)))))   ";
    R5RSLexer lexer = new R5RSLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    R5RSParser parser = new R5RSParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

and to generate a lexer & parser, compile all Java source files and run the main class, do:

```
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/R5RS$ java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool R5RS.g 
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/R5RS$ javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/R5RS$ java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/R5RS$
```

The fact that nothing is being printed on the console means the parser (and lexer) didn't find any errors with the provided source.

Note that I have no Unit tests and have only tested the single Scheme source inside the `Main` class. If you find errors in the ANTLR grammar, I'd appreciate to hear about them so I can fix the grammar. In due time, I'll probably commit the grammar to the official [ANTLR Wiki](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list).

Comment: @Sebastian, note that I encountered a small mistake in the `sequence` rule, which I fixed (see the edited answer). And you're welcome, of course.

Comment: @ Bart, i fixed now my grammar according to yours and i have no problems running a test class. however, when i use the build-in interpreter of ANTLRWorks or ANTLRIDE, i get a FailedPredicateException. Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: @Sebastian, yes, ANTLRWorks' interpreter is buggy and above that, it does not work when there are predicates in your grammar. Best perform your tests using ANTLRWorks' debugger (which I don't use, but know it does a good job), or perform your tests with custom classes like the one I posted above.