# ANTLR grammar for scheme R5RS

Tags: scheme, antlr, antlr3, r5rs

I'm beginner in ANTLR and I'm learning it by an example. I use C as my target language.
The example is a Scheme R5RS grammar file taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344766/antlr-resolving-non-ll-problems-and-syntactic-predicates/6349009#6349009), with a little modification(rename the grammar name and add some options with the grammar specification untouched).

antlr generated the lexer and parser, and I compile it with a test `main()` in which I just do some initialization and simply call the parser. When runing the test program with a piece of scheme code, the parser detect some syntax error(which should not happen!)

`main` function in test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "r5rsLexer.h"
#include "r5rsParser.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pANTLR3_UINT8 fname;
  pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM input;
  pr5rsLexer lexer;
  pANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_STREAM tstream;
  pr5rsParser parser;
  r5rsParser_parse_return parse_return;

  if (argc != 2)
    {
      ANTLR3_FPRINTF(stderr, "usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
    }
  fname = (pANTLR3_UINT8)argv[1];
  input = antlr3FileStreamNew(fname, ANTLR3_ENC_8BIT);
  if (!input)
    {
      ANTLR3_FPRINTF(stderr, "open file stream failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  lexer = r5rsLexerNew(input);
  if (!lexer)
    {
      ANTLR3_FPRINTF(stderr, "new lexer failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  tstream =
    antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew(ANTLR3_SIZE_HINT, TOKENSOURCE(lexer));
  if (!tstream)
    {
      ANTLR3_FPRINTF(stderr, "open token stream failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  parser = r5rsParserNew(tstream);
  if (!parser)
    {
      ANTLR3_FPRINTF(stderr, "new parser failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  parse_return = parser->parse(parser);
  printf("succeed!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

scheme code in test.scm:

```
(define-syntax should-be
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ test-id value expression)
     (let ((return-value expression))
         (if (not (equal? return-value value))
           (for-each (lambda (v) (display v))
                     `("Failure: " test-id ", expected '"
                     value "', got '" ,return-value "'." #\newline))
           (for-each (lambda (v) (display v))
                     '("Passed: " test-id #\newline)))))))
(should-be 1.1 0
 (let ((cont #f))
   (letrec ((x (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) (set! cont c) 0)))
            (y (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) (set! cont c) 0))))
     (if cont
         (let ((c cont))
           (set! cont #f)
           (set! x 1)
           (set! y 1)
           (c 0))
         (+ x y)))))
```

the terminal output:

```
$> ls
r5rs.g test.c test.scm
$> antlr3 r5rs.g
$> ls
r5rs.g r5rs.tokens r5rsLexer.c r5rsLexer.h r5rsParser.c r5rsParser.h test.c test.scm
$> gcc -o test test.c r5rsLexer.c r5rsParser.c -lantlr3c
$> ./test test.scm
test.scm(1)  : error 4 : Unexpected token, at offset 0
near [Index: 1 (Start: 154513905-Stop: 154513917) ='define-syntax', type<5> Line:1 
LinePos:0]
: unexpected input...
expected one of : <EOR>
test.scm(2)  : error 4 : Unexpected token, at offset 3
near [Index: 8 (Start: 154513932-Stop: 154513943) ='syntax-rules', type<7> Line: 2 
LinePos:3]
: unexpected input...
expected one of : <EOR>
test.scm(2)  : error 4 : Unexpected token, at offset 17
near [Index: 11 (Start: 154513946-Stop: 154513946) =')', type<82> Line: 2 LinePos:17]
: unexpected input...
expected one of : <EOR>
test.scm(2)  : error 4 : Unexpected token, at offset 17
near [Index: 11 (Start: 154513946-Stop: 154513946) =')', type<82> Line: 2 LinePos:17]
: unexpected input...
expected one of : <EOR>
```

I've read through the grammar specification and it is correct. I can't figure out where the problem lies ... can someone help? thanks!

===================== reply =========================

Following the grammar rule of `pattern` and `template`, I went down to the code fragment below. I think the parse is going to match `template` with it and failed because `template` doesn't have an `quasiquote` alternative.

```
`("Failure: " test-id ", expected '" value "', got '" ,return-value "'." #\newline)
```

I believe the grammar rule for `template` follows the R5RS specification correctly, and the code is accepted by other R5Rs scheme implementation(I tested it in scheme48 and guile). How can this happen?

I think there must be something wrong in my analyse ...

Comment: You are looking at it backwards. You have a valid piece of scheme code and a grammar you've picked up from the Internet. While I admit that grammar looks pretty good, you've obviously found an edge case it doesn't cover. I don't think you should question yourself about it.

Comment: ok, I think I'd better leave the trouble there for a moment. Thank you very much @Slartibartfast

Answer (score 1):

It is a back-tick in

```
`("Failure: " test-id ", expected '"
```

that trips the parser.

If you follow grammar rules for pattern and template, you'll see that they don't reach `quasiquotation` rule that match both `QUASIQUOTE` and back-tick. They do however reach `expressionKeyword` that contains `QUASIQUOTE`.

You should fix grammar to include abbreviated forms in template or fix your input not to use them.

Comment: thank you very much! @Slartibartfast but still I have troubles... see my edition to your answer above.

Comment: sorry, @Slartibartfast I don't know why my edition didn't take effect. I have edited my origin post to include my question.