# Java, how to recognize a part of a token as a separate token?

Tags: java, string, parsing, scheme

Hopefully my title isn't completely terrible. I don't really know what this should be called. I'm trying to write a very basic scheme parser in Java. The issue I'm having is with implementation.

I open a file, and I want to parse individual tokens:

```
while(sc.hasNext()) {           
   System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

Generally, to get tokens, this is fine. But in scheme, recognizing the begining and end of a list is crucial; my program's functionality depends on this, so I need a way to treat a token such as:

```
(define
```

or

```
poly))
```

As multiple tokens, where any parentheses is its own token:

```
(
define
poly
)
)
```

If I can do that, I can properly recognize different symbols to add to my symtab, and know when/how to add nodes to my parse tree.

The Java API shows that the scanner class doesn't have any methods for doing exactly what I want. The closest thing I could think of is using the parantheses as custom delimiters, which would make each token clean enough to be recognized more easily by my logic, but then what happens to my parentheses?

Another method I'm thinking about is forgoing the Java tokenizer, and just scanning char by char until I find a complete symbol.

What should I do? Try to work around the Java scanner methods, or just do a character by character approach?

Comment: it's not only whitespace and parens, but various quotation marks too. Delimiter based scanning won't work there.

Comment: related posts on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376475/antlr-grammar-for-scheme-r5rs, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344766/antlr-resolving-non-ll-problems-and-syntactic-predicates/6349009#6349009.

Comment: @WillNess Those links would be more helpful if they weren't so advanced. The program I'm working on is for a prequisite course for compiler design, which is not even a required course at my university. I also understand now that I can't use a delimiter based approach, so I think a character based one is my only option...

Comment: looks like it; you can always cook up something ad-hoc, for a basic syntax (without recognizing, say, advanced number syntax e.g. (radix etc.)). Or without the backquote even.

Comment: @WillNess This is the approach my partner and I took. The code is slightly convoluted and probably a little inefficient, but it works. The assignment doesn't call for much beyond recognizing reserved words and some of the syntax. Now I just have to write the rest of it...

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get your terminology straight.  `(define` is not a single token; it's a `(` token followed by a `define` one.  Similarly, `poly))` is not a single token, it's three.

Don't let `java.util.Scanner` (that's what you're using, right?) throw you for a loop -- when you say "Generally, to get tokens, this is fine", I say no, it's not.  Don't settle for what it provides if it's not enough.

To correctly tokenize Scheme code, I'd expect you need to at least be able to deal with regular languages.  That would probably be very tough to do using `Scanner`, so here's a couple of alternatives:

- learn and apply a tried-and-true parsing tool like Antlr or Lex.  Will be beneficial for any of your future parsing projects
- roll your own regular expression approach (I don't know Scheme well enough to be sure that this will work) for tokenizing, but don't forget that you need at least context-free for full parsing
- learn about parser combinators and recursive descent parsing, which are relatively easy to implement by hand -- and you'll end up learning a ton about Java's type system